# Steam doesn't start and says that these packages need to be installed

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, steam

I used `sudo apt install steam` and got this error message when I tried to run Steam:

```
Package libc6:i386 needs to be installed
Package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 needs to be installed
Package libgl1:i386 needs to be installed
Package steam-libs-amd64:amd64 needs to be installed
Package steam-libs-i386:i386 needs to be installed
Package xdg-desktop-portal needs to be installed
Package xdg-desktop-portal-gtk needs to be installed
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1376594/edit) to show us complete input and output. If you are following instructions, include a link to those instructions.

Comment: Also include the Ubuntu release/version and how did you installed Steam.

Comment: The easiest way to put complete input and output into your question is to highlight it in your terminal, then copy (not screenshot), then paste into your question. If you understand Markdown, then use it to correct the formatting. The current jumble of random unformatted output is both hard to read and lacks the usual details that we need to help you. Also, the tags you have chosen suggests that your question still seems to lack the complete sequence of commands that you used. We are not clairvoyant.

Comment: how do i find the version im using because im using the one that comes with chrome os

Comment: I couldn't install Steam via `apt` either. Try installing it via `flatpak`.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm both impressed and puzzled. Installing some distro over (or alongside) Chrome OS is an impressive achievement. It requires skill and patience. So it's puzzling that, though you are skilled and patient, you cannot explain what distro or version you installed nor provide the information we need to help you.

Comment: no its through the settings under advanced

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --fix-missing` and  `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Answer (score 1):

Run this command to install the packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1:i386 steam-libs-amd64:amd64 steam-libs-i386:i386 xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
```

Comment: An improvement would be to run this simulated installation command: `apt  install --simulate libc6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1:i386 steam-libs-amd64:amd64 steam-libs-i386:i386 xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk`  first (without `sudo`) to check for errors.